# Will the program terminate itself if the thunk is too large?

Tags: haskell

As I have known, Haskell is lazy. Computation like `foldl` will not be executed immediately, instead, a thunk is built. But there is a problem, if there is a bad programme that keep constructing thunks and postpone the evaluation, for example, `foldl` a infinite list, will Haskell kill the program by raising a exception/SYSCALL to avoid running out of memory? If it doesn't, is there some ways, that we can write some auxiliary codes, to achieve such purpose?

Answer (score 3):

By default, Haskell programs do nothing special to avoid running out of memory, leaving it to the OS's memory management mechanisms to handle whatever happens. Typically, this means the OS will kill this program when it demands more memory than the system can support (though sometimes the mechanism is more complicated).

If you'd like the program to die before the OS would kill it, you can set a maximum heap size by enabling `-rtsopts` at compile time, and using the command-line flags `+RTS -M<size>` at run time. See the manual for more details and instructions on making this the default on a per-executable basis.